# Centering spans in window

Tags: html, css

I have a row of spans that I'd like to be centred on the page, or in a canvas. Is there a CSS quality I should use?

```
<div>
  <span style='width:100px;height:100px;padding:50px;border:4px solid black;border-color:#032441;border-radius:90px;background-color:transparent' class=div id=rowOneColumnOne>

  </span>

  <span style='width:100px;height:100px;padding:50px;border:4px solid black;border-color:#032441;border-radius:90px;background-color:transparent' class=div id=rowOneColumnTwo>

  </span>

  <span style='width:100px;height:100px;padding:50px;border:4px solid black;border-color:#032441;border-radius:90px;background-color:transparent' class=div id=rowOneColumnThree>

  </span>

  <span style='width:100px;height:100px;padding:50px;border:4px solid black;border-color:#032441;border-radius:90px;background-color:transparent' class=div id=rowOneColumnFour>

  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *FlexBox* technique for this.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

div span {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span style='width:100px;height:100px;padding:50px;border:4px solid black;border-color:#032441;border-radius:90px;background-color:transparent' class=div id=rowOneColumnOne>

  </span>

  <span style='width:100px;height:100px;padding:50px;border:4px solid black;border-color:#032441;border-radius:90px;background-color:transparent' class=div id=rowOneColumnTwo>

  </span>

  <span style='width:100px;height:100px;padding:50px;border:4px solid black;border-color:#032441;border-radius:90px;background-color:transparent' class=div id=rowOneColumnThree>

  </span>

  <span style='width:100px;height:100px;padding:50px;border:4px solid black;border-color:#032441;border-radius:90px;background-color:transparent' class=div id=rowOneColumnFour>

  </span>
</div>
```

Note: `row` is a default value of `flex-direction` property. So you can skip that.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to change the opening div to:

```
<div align="center" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 0px; top: 50%;">
<span ...
```

This way you should have them centered aswell!